# JUnit - make sure that a function is invoked on every path

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I know how to make sure that a function has been invoked, using:

```
mockito.verify
```

now, I want to make sure that on every path of the function (every 'if', 'if else' and 'else') - the function was invoked.
I can basically write unit test for every case, but I want to make sure that if any further cases will be added - there will also be invocation to that method.

Comment: Are you saying that if the code changes you want the test to automatically cover the new part?

Comment: @john16384 ah yes, a framework doing that would be really nice;)

Comment: Well it doesn't work that way, expect to update your test case every time you modify the things you are testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unit testing alone will not do that. You have to look into using **[coverage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_coverage)** in order to get there.

Unit testing can only tell you if the paths that were taken resulted in a "valid" result; but there is no knowledge of "all paths" that exist; and if they were all hit.

So you want to turn [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Code_Coverage_Tools) for example and learn which coverage tool would work for you.

When you are working with eclipse or intellij, those things work out of the box; you can install plugins like cobertura or eclemma within eclipse; and then do a "run unit test with coverage".

But of course: that only results in a number. You then have to look carefully at your code to understand if you are happy with that number (where those IDEs make that really easy; they can show you your source code, and which paths were taken).

Meaning: *coverage* is a whole **concept**, and you have to understand what that means; and in which way you can make that concept *helpful* for your daily work. For example, you the last thing you want is your boss giving you a specific target goal for coverage.

And just to be sure: there is no tooling that tells you: you added new code, and now *this specific method invocation* is no longer coming through all parts. What coverage gives you is that you had 75.32% coverage before your change; and afterwards, it went down to 74.01% ... the rest is then up to you.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the issue.

Comment: You are very welcome. And just wondering: the quick accept is nice; could I do something to improve the answer to also make it upvote-worthy?

Answer (score 0):

> now, I want to make sure that on every path of the function (every 'if', 'if else' and 'else') - the function was invoked.

You don't want that.

The misunderstanding is that you don't test "the code". You test *public observable behavior*. In your case the behavior is that your unit under test (UuT) (after doing other stuff) calls a method on a dependency (I hope).

You don't want to test "the code" because it may change for becoming cleaner and/or support more behavior. But then you don't want to change your existing tests since they will guarantee that the desired behavior is preserved during your refactoring.

On the other hand each test method should verify *exactly one expectation* about the UuTs behavior. This means that you should already have one test method for each execution path though your `if`/`else` cascade. So all you have to do is to add the `verify()` instruction to each of this test methods.

Finally you may have an easier job testing your code if you force *Single Layer of Abstraction* principle which basically says that a method either calls methods on some dependencies (aka "dispatching"), calls internal methods or does low level operations. This principle may lead to a design, where the "low level" stuff your UuT currently does moves to a new dependency so that your UuT only needs to do two calls on some dependencies in a certain order...

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this issue before where I needed to tightly test bound the switch cases, and I was desperate enough to do that.

I am asuming test coverage analysis is not enough for you. For me, the if-else conditions part was so critical that changing something unintentionally could have proved greatly disastrous, so I could not afford to leave a failure prone code and I needed a test case to satisfy myself.

How I satisfied myself is here:

1: Changed the conditions such as if..else, etc to a swich case variable - TaskSwitcherEnum, say taskSwitcher, and performed all sorts of operations under various possible values of TaskSwitcherEnum.

```
switch (taskSwitcher){
    case TaskSwitcherEnum.Task_Type_1: 
        //do Something before break
        break;
    case TaskSwitcherEnum.Task_Type_2: 
        //do Something again
        break;
    ...
}
```

2: Tightly tested the desired method for all possible values of taskSwitcherEnum. `Mockito.verify()`, whether required task method is called once, for each given TaskSwitcherEnum value.

3: Finally did a junit like this:

```
assertEquals("Task performance strategy is designed to handle only five cases.", 5, taskSwitcherEnum.values().length);
```

Doing this made sure [at least test covered] following things:

1: That my code has only desired branches, and any other code branch addition/deletion is caught by a test case.

2: That each branch does it's desired job by calling a method that I want, through testing on every particular Enum values against a called method.

Gist of the whole answer is, sometimes a little design change helps a lot.